# Can I run Backblaze and Crashplan together on a single PC at the same time to backup to two destinations?

Tags: windows-8.1, backup

Can I run Backblaze and Crashplan together on a single PC at the same time to backup to two destinations?

I'm not too sure as I wanted to use both Backblaze for speed and Crashplan for data retention and ease of restoration.  Will running the two software together on Windows 8.1 x64 cause file corruption issues when backed up to Crashplan/Backblaze?  (i.e. the backed up files on Crashplan/Backblaze are corrupted)

Another question, will running these two software simultaneously cause data corruption on the files stored on the hard drive?

Comment: Why would reading and uploading a file cause data corruption?  Files are read simultaneously by multiple applications all the time.

Comment: Because I'm afraid that uploading a single file to two sites cause issues.

Comment: The local file is copied then uploaded.  The original file is never altered.

Comment: CrashPlan have ended their [consumer backup service](https://www.crashplan.com/en-us/consumer/nextsteps/)... so your question will very soon become moot.

Comment: @Tetsujin - You can still signup for their business plan but it isn't identical to the consumer backup service.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can - I do that all the time. I have Crashplan and Carbon installed on multiple Windows 10 machines.

The backup software never uploads the actual file - it creates a copy for themselves and that is what gets uploaded. Ramhound correctly pointed that out in the comments